# how to become a registered developer?

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-graph-api

I want to try the new graphapi messaging endpoint of facebook but here is the catch.

"We are providing early access to this API for registered developer accounts only until the new messaging system is broadly available."

How to become one?

edit: and what are the other benefits of a registered developer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an application you're already a registered developer. The message refers to the fact that the messaging API is not broadly available and only works for your own {developer} account at this time

Comment: I see. Thank you. But why I have this error on graph api explorer message?

input: me/messages

output: { "error": { "message": "Unsupported get request.", "type": "GraphMethodException" } }

Comment: Because you're making an unsupported GET request; whatever you're trying to access isn't something which is accessible via the API

Comment: Sorry, but this confuses me, I thought messages is already supported at least for a developer account like mine.